# Grunt task generates a loop in my console

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify, gruntfile

I use the task uglify, cssmin and others grunt tasks.

For example, if I make just a change in my javascript or css files... the console shows me a loop about ten times:
[image]

... ETC

All changes and tasks works perfectly, but this curious loop is very strange.

This is my Gruntfile.js:

```
    //Gruntfile.js
    module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

    // Watch task config
    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: "scss/*.scss",
        tasks: ['sass']
      },
      cssmin: {
        files: "css/*.css",
        tasks: ['cssmin']
      },
      uglify: {
        files: "js/*.js",
        tasks: ['uglify']
      }
    },

    // Sass task config
    sass: {
        dev: {
            files: {
                // fichero destino  // fichero .scss
                "css/custom.css" : "scss/custom.scss"
            }
        }
    },

    // BrowserSync task config
    browserSync: {
      default_options: {
        bsFiles: {
          src: [
            "css/*.css",
            "js/*.js",
            "*.html"
          ]
        },
        options: {
          watchTask: true,
          proxy: "tutorialmaterialize.dev"
          }
        }
      },

    // UnCSS task config  
    uncss: {
        dist: {
            options: {
               //Estilos que queremos limpiar
               stylesheets : ['css/materialize.min.css'],

               //Estilos que no queremos limpiar
               ignoreSheets: [/custom.css/], 
            },
            files: {
                    //Archivo css de salida    //Scanea las clases, ids, etc de este html
                    'css/materialize.min.css': ['index.html']
            }
        }
    },

    // Cssmin task config
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        shorthandCompacting: false,
        roundingPrecision: -1
      },
      target: {
        files: {//Fichero combinado   //Ficheros que vamos a combinar, 2 .css
                'css/allcss.min.css': ['css/custom.css', 'css/materialize.min.css']
        }
      }
    },

    //Uglify task config  
    uglify: {
      build: {
        src: 'js/custom.js',//Ruta de fichero de entrada
        dest: 'js/custom.min.js'//Ruta del fichero minificado
      }
    }

  });

  //Cargamos los grunt plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

 //Default task
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync', 'watch']);
};
```

How can i fix this? Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the file output by uglify is being watched for changes, triggering uglify again, and so on...

Note that watch is configured to watch every file in the directory `js`, and uglify is configured to output the results into `js/custom.min.js`.

Change one of these, and the loop will stop.

For example (depending on what watch plugin you're using), you can probably change the configuration of `watch` to watch the directory, excluding this single file, using the array and `!` syntax, like this:

```
watch: {
  uglify: {
    files: ["js/*.js", "!js/custom.min.js"],
    tasks: ['uglify']
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding  '!js/custom.min.js' to your files for the watch. Looks like you are watching for changes to that file which triggers the task to be run again

```
  uglify: {
    files: ["js/*.js","!js/custom.min.js"],
    tasks: ['uglify']
  }
```